# Is it safe to use an a mounter encrypted partition with unencrypted linux system?

Tags: linux, encryption

Let's say linux is installed on a clear partition is it safe to mount an encrypted partition and use it for data ? Won't it cause the key to be stored somewhere in clear or logs to tell something on what's on the encrypted partition ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, an encrypted partition for storage / data is safe, if you use a good program like dm-crypt / LUKS.

An encrypted home folder is safe too, using eCryptFS is well tested and most disros can use it well.

It won't be a total secret that there's encrypted data, but it will be unreadable data. Just don't store your passphrase in an unencrypted file anywhere, don't forget it, and make **BACKUPS of the keys / header / data**.